# How to extract and pair up bits of a key?

Tags: matlab, encryption, input, passwords, grouping

```
function k = q43042300

key=input('Enter the key','s');
keyarr=dec2bin(key,8)

temp=1;
v=char(zeros(1,16*8));
for i=1 :16
  for j=1:8
    v(temp)=keyarr(i,j);
    temp=temp+1;
  end
end
temp=1;

for i=1:16:128
  k(temp)=v(i:i+15) % Error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
  temp=temp+1
end
```

I want to get a key like `'abcdefghijklmnop'` as an input, then I want to convert the characters into binary digits (such that I get 128 bits).
Then I want to pair every consecutive 16 bits into a single one field but this is giving an error.

Comment: What error is that?

Comment: the assignment should contain the same number of elements

Comment: You have multiple assignments in your code. Which line is this coming from. Please describe your problem in detail. Also, I don't understand your scheme here. Can you give some example inputs and outputs? What is `k`? It's used but never defined.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly (that is, convert the provided key into 8 groups of 16 binary digits), this is what you were trying to do:

```
k = reshape(dec2bin(input('Enter the key: ','s'),8).',16,[]).';
```

You don't need loops, just some reshaping.